# Random image of day (PHP)

Tags: php, html, image, random

I'm trying to add a simple random image of the day script. It doesn't point to the right file location though. Here is the code:

```html
<?php 
 $i=0; 
 $path="images";  
 $ext = "jpg";  
 $extra= "alt=\"Random Image\" float=\"left\""; 
 if ($handle = opendir($path)) {  
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {  
    if (substr($file,strlen($file)-3,3)==$ext)  
{        $imgs[$i++]=$file; 
} 
    } 
   closedir($handle);  
  $today=getdate(); 

srand($today['mday']+$today['month']+$today['year']);  

   $r=rand(0,$i-1); 

   echo("<img src=images/\"$imgs[$r]\" $extra>"); 

 }

?>
```

The image source when I right click and check properties is adding %22 before and after the file. EX: mobile/images/%22image.jpg%22

Therefore, the image isn't showing because of it I presume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `%22` is actually that superfluous `"` inside your url source, remove those:

```
echo "<img src=\"images/{$imgs[$r]}\" alt=\"Photo\" />";
               ^ opening            ^ closing
```